# Date Format in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need a date fomat to convert date time to short date.

Input:

```
2013-06-02 00:00:00
```

Output

```
Sun 2/6
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`date.ToString("ddd d/M");`

The format is `ddd d/M`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 6, 2);
string ss = dt.ToString("ddd d/M");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a quick google search will get you a long way.

By following the example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx), the solution would be:

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-02 00:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//substitute with custom culture if needed
string formattedDate = dateValue.ToString("ddd d/M");
```